# application shows force close only on booting of emulator/phone as the broadcast receiver shows exception

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, forceclose

The application shows force close only at reboot of emulator/phone. It has two broadcast receiver 1 to check phone state and answer the call and other to keep a notification icon on top. The receiver monitoring phone state gives the following exception only at booting otherwise the app work fine. log is shown below

```
05-20 12:48:15.688: INFO/Andros:AnsTheCall:receiver(218): initialised the receiver
05-20 12:48:15.707: WARN/dalvikvm(218): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.andros.AnsTheCall.AnsTheCallReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.andro.AnsTheCall.AnsTheCallReceiver.onReceive(AnsTheCallReceiver.java:37)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
05-20 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     ... 10 more
```

Please help

```
public class AnsTheCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String TAG = "Andros:AnsTheCall:receiver";
public selectedTabType attentFlag = selectedTabType.TYPE_INVALID;

private Intent AnsTheCallServiceIntent = null;
public String contactName = null;
public String contactEmail = "";
public int PhoneNumberCount= 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    // Check phone state
    String phone_state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    String lastPhoneNumber = null;
    Log.i(TAG,"initialised the receiver");

    if (phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) && prefs.getBoolean("appEnabled", false)) {
        int is_starred = isStarred(context, phoneNumber);
```

Comment: post your BOOT_COMPLETED receiver code..

Comment: thanks for your response..now the post is updated.

Comment: Is this posted code ur boot complted receiver? In this case intentExtras will not carry TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE and your string might be null bcz of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is at `com.andro.AnsTheCall.AnsTheCallReceiver.onReceive(AnsTheCallReceiver.java:37` this is causing your service to force close.

> 12:48:15.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 05-20 12:48:15.827:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): at
>   com.andro.AnsTheCall.AnsTheCallReceiver.onReceive(AnsTheCallReceiver.java:37)
>   05-20 12:48:15.827:

Comment: at `com.andro.AnsTheCall.AnsTheCallReceiver.onReceive(AnsTheCallReceiver.java:37` . i have `if (phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) && prefs.getBoolean("appEnabled", false)) {` .I need this as i have to detect call and to answer it. it works fine except only at switching on my device the app shows force close dialog box .But it still works well at back ground even after the force close dialog box. :-)

Comment: Your phone_state is null in case of booting up.
    String phone_state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE); is null in case of Boot Completed.

Comment: `if(phone_state !=null && phoneNumber!=null)` then check for `if (phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) && prefs.getBoolean("appEnabled", false)) {` you can write your own logic for this null scenario.